# Https post with angular mobile ui on phonegap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, post, https

I've been trying to use $http.post from Angular Mobile UI on phonegap, but it doesn't seem to work.
It does work when I use http, which the server still has available, but only from the internal network. Once I start using https, it doesn't work anymore.
The phonegap console still tells me it was a success, but also gives me an error.
"[phonegap] Proxy error for url: https://blablabla.com:port/folders/here undefined
[phonegap] EPROTO"

Here's the code that doesn't work. Though I did change the url here.

```
console.log("tryLogin");
    $http.post("https://blablabla:port/folders/here", $scope.loginData, {'headers':{'Content-Type':'application/json', 'Accept':'*/*', 'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate', 'Accept-Language': 'nl-NL;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,it;q=0.2'}})
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config, statusText)
    {
        console.log("tryLogin success");
        console.log("status: " + status);
        console.log("data: " + data);
        console.log("headers: " + headers);
        console.log("config: " + config);
        console.log("statusText: " +statusText);
        $scope.data = data;
        $scope.status = status;
        $scope.headers = headers;
        $scope.config = config;
    })          
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config)
    {
        console.log("tryLogin error");
        $scope.data = data;
        $scope.status = status;
        $scope.headers = headers;
        $scope.config = config
    });
```

I had some similar probems  when I made the same project before as a native Android app, after switching from http to https, but managed to fix those by accepting all certificates. And then I had to enable more cipher suites to support API level 20 and up. But I did manage to get it working there.

UPDATE: The problem seems to be with the certificate. An intermediary certificate should be added to the server.
Currently I'm still trying to get around that with the cordovaHTTP plugin.

Comment: Is your server configured correctly? Phonegap is very strict about server certificates. You can use https://sslcheck.globalsign.com/ to be sure (You'll need an A rating)

Comment: @MaartenBicknese I have no idea. The check app from your link drops the ssl port the server is configured with. It's not the default port. The one from digicert however tells me it's issued by GlobalSign Domain Validation CA - SHA256 - G2, but it's not signed by a trusted authority.

Comment: https://www.geocerts.com/ssl_checker This one seems to accept custom ports.

Comment: @MaartenBicknese That one says the server gives an invalid SSL response.
https://www.digicert.com/help doesn't seem to have that kind of problem, though.

Comment: If it works with http and fails with https it's a certificate problem

Comment: @jcesarmobile It probably is. I'm trying to work around that now with a plugin that's supposed to enable certificate pinning, but I'm not having muc luck getting phonegap to actually load the plugin.

Comment: certificate pinning just help you to check that the server certificate is the one that is supposed to be, but won't solver your issue, you have to use a valid certificate

Comment: @jcearmobile The server does have a certificate. It just doesn't seem to be signed by a trusted authority. Would that be a problem?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem